# How to insert 1 row of data into another table single column

Tags: mysql

I have two different tables,
First table structure:

```
`requestId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `correlationId` text NOT NULL,
 `processRegistryId` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `createdDateTime` datetime NOT NULL,
 `lastUpdatedDateTime` datetime NOT NULL,
 `status` text NOT NULL,
 `requestPayload` text NOT NULL,
```

Second table structure:

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `primaryValidatedRequestId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `transferOutId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `policyNumber` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `correlationId` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `createdDateTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `OMIMAGE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `suspendedCase` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `futureDated` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `isprocessed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
```

Now I want to insert data into first table like `requestId` is primary key, `correlationId` from second table,`processRegistryId` is hardcode,`createdDateTime` is now timestamp, `lastUpdatedDateTime` is also some datetime stamp,`status` as hardcoded, 
but coming to `requestPayload`, the data should be all the columns data as string from second table.

Comment: Not sure why you want to do it, but you could JSON encode the results from fetching the one table into the requestPayload field.

Comment: can you please tell me how to JSON encode the result

Comment: Have a look at json_object (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object), it's a bit long winded for all those columns, but the problem is that just concat'ing all the values together just gives you a meaningless string at the end.  You can also change the columns to being JSON.